# Button "Fn" not working for brightness

Tags: windows, sony-vaio

I have a laptop Sony Vaio VPC-CW21FX after installing windows 8 release preview, my fn key does not work for the screen brightness.
help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a driver from Sony to get the specialty keys working.  This is usually the "HKServ" driver/process (The Hotkey Service).

This may not (yet) be available from Sony as Windows 8 has not been officially released.

You can get a few versions of the HKServer application from Sony's Vaio FTP site [here](ftp://ftp.vaio-link.com/PUB/Vaio/hotkey/).  Perhaps one of them will work for you.

Comment: @BramWinda which file worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to insure that the Sony software is installed. I'm not sure which one pertains to <kbd>Fn</kbd>, but one of them probably does.

If possible, try installing them in compatibility mode, if installing them normally doesn't fix your problem.

Does <kbd>Fn</kbd> work for volume?

Comment: Fn work for volume

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Windows 8 in my Sony CS series laptop.

After installing...

1. Original - Sony® Notebook Utilities
2. System Components Sony® Firmware Extension Parser Device Driver
3. System Components Sony® Shared Library
   for windows 7 x64 and last update graphic driver, problem is solved.

Control settings appear to have looked like this before in Windows 7.
Notice that you must first activate .Net farmework 3.5 in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

In VAIO Control Center, go to Image Quality and switch off the automatic brightness adjustments.

Good luck!