# VAIO , brightness

Tags: brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button “Fn” not working for brightness](https://superuser.com/questions/437931/button-fn-not-working-for-brightness)

I have Vaio , VPCF117HG , and I cant use Fn for change my brightness  , I download all drivers for update but nothing change , my fn for change volume is working but for other thing is not working , any way to solve it ?

Comment: Which OS? Which drivers did you install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button "Fn" not working for brightness](http://superuser.com/questions/437931/button-fn-not-working-for-brightness) also see [Adjust screen brightness hotkeys not working in Vaio laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/419948/adjust-screen-brightness-hotkeys-not-working-in-vaio-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

- Right click the Power Panel icon in the system tray (looks like a
  battery)
- Click on Edit/Create Profiles
- On the left side of the new screen, click on 'Maximum Battery Life'
- Then on the right side of your screen, click on 'LCD Brightness'
- You should see 9 levels of brightness. Level 9 is the brightest.
- You need to click on the Save icon. (Looks like a disk at top left
  of screen)
- Close the window after you save the changes made.
- You must restart the notebook in order for the changes to take
  effect.

Comment: When I click the power icon in the system tray of Windows 8.1, I see a pop-out showing me two different power plans with an option for "adjust screen brightness" and "more power options". I've changed the screen brightness value for the various power plans, to no effect. For which O/S are your instructions for?